# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver in JBuilder 7

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am using jtds 1.3.1 jar file to connect with MSSQL server 2008. For this I have configured library and JDK in JBuilder7, while running application from JBuilder 7 compiler everything found okay but whenever I am trying run via .exe application build by JBUilder7 from WInXP platform getting error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver".

Can anyone help to give me further guideline in what extend I need to make executable file in JBuilder 7?

Answer (score 0):

Usually drivers to the database get resolved in runtime, for example the drovers class name read from properties file osr XML file configuration. It can boil down to

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver")
```

This code gets compiled without an error even if the driver itself is not present.

What you should do is to download the driver's jar and add the jar to the configuration of your project. This way jbuilder will add the jar to the classpath of the project when it runs it.

Adding a jar is easy, I don't have Jbuilder to check,[here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/399825/java/java/JBuilder-Adding-Jar-File-ClassPath) someone gets instructions of how to do it

Hope this helps

Comment: Already I have added *.jar file in JBuilder 7 Tools--> Configure Libraries --> ... while compiling through JBuilder7 everything found okay but whenever I am trying to run application by .exe getting error classNotFound exception....

Comment: @AhsanMd.SajidKhan Then you are not specifying the correct classpath at runtime.